# How to add input type date and time into local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, dom-events, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to insert the date and time elements into localstorage. I'm using `datetimepicker`. The events `onchange` and `oninput` are not working as I want them to work because you need to select the date and time by mouse and this will add value into this input field. On mentioned events it is working but I will need to set it up when the user selects the date by mouse. Current code below in snippet for ref.

```js
let date_time_array = [];
    date_time_array.push(reschedule_date, reschedule_time);
    date_time_array.forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener('input', event => {
            localStorage.setItem(el.name, el.value);
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: `datetimepicker` is not a standard html input - The closest is `datetime-local` - _datetimepicker_ is a jquery plugin. Please let us know if you are using the jquery plugin.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: I'm using the bootstrap datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

So, I found an issue here. `onchange/oninput/input/dp.change/change.dp/change` events are not working in my use case. It seems that the event was changed to `change.datetimepicker`.

**Current refactored code below:**

```js
var currentDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
$("#reschedule-date").datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    minDate: currentDate,
    collapse: false,
    debug: true,
});

$("#reschedule-date").on('change.datetimepicker', function(e){
    localStorage.setItem('reschedule_date', $(this).val());
});

$("#reschedule-date").val(localStorage.getItem('reschedule_date'));
```

Comment: These common JavaScript events only work, if the change in the field content happend directly by user interaction - i.e., the user typed or copy&pasted the value into the input field. They do not fire, if the field value gets set _via JavaScript_ - and that is the case here with such datepicker scripts. _“It seems that the event was changed to change.datetimepicker”_ - nothing was “changed”, the datepicker just _added_ its own, custom event, specifically for this purpose.